# Why are all my routes displaying a 404 page?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am working locally on a webpage in laravel with wamp, everything is going smoothly except that my routes are not working I have watched youtube videos and exactly followed their instructions

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view ('client-side');
});
```

this is returning a 404 page
also I have tried returning a simple echo with this code

```
Route::get('/hello', function()
{
    echo 'hello man'
});
```

And this also returns a 404 page, I dont understand why this isnt working, ty in advance

Comment: are you adding your routes to `routes/web.php` file?

Comment: @HafezDivandari Yes I am adding them there, also the views arent in any folders

Comment: Do `php artisan routes:list` on the command line, and compare them to the route you're trying to access.

Comment: @AndrisZandris, the document root is the /public folder?

Answer (score 1):

You said you were working locally with WAMP. But you were not specific about how you were trying to access your website. So, I am wondering if you need to add public to the end of your URL. See, Laravel reads from the public directory. If you are using WAMP, then most likely you haven't don't have it reading from public.
So, let me give you an example. If you are using myWebSite as your directory from your WAMP directory, if you haven't set your hosts files, etc., then you would need to access your website like this http://localhost/myWebSite/public. Make sense?
Another way of accessing your website would be to use the built in web server. From a terminal window in the root directory of your project, type php artisan serve in the terminal window. You should then get a message that says "Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000" so then you should be able to access your website at http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is in calling url.
Image that your project in htdocs.So you should call your page likethis:

```
localhost/{YourProjectFolderName}/public/{route}
```

If you want remove `public` from url you should cut its content and past it in previous path and edit `index.php` file.

If you want remove `{YourProjectFolderName}` from your url you should edit config of wampp.